# How to install an Edimax EW-7833UAC in 19.10

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, 19.10

Updated xubuntu to 19.10 which killed wifi. I do have the correct driver, I think, installed.

In Terminal the following output shows after trying the "dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21" command.

Module rtl8814au/4.3.21 already installed on kernel 5.3.0-19-generic/x86_64

I can run update 19.10 with kernel 5.0.0.32 and it works fine.

What would you suggest I try next.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have one and it shows `ID 7392:a833 Edimax ` and I haven't seen any driver on github that claims to work on 5.3 but https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues might as it works for rtl8812au, rtl8814au, and rtl8821au

Comment: If your USB ID is the same as @Jeremy31, also show us: `modinfo 8814au | grep A833` .

Comment: @Jeremy31 zebulon2 compiles with warnings on 5.3.0-xx. I don't have the device, so I don't know if it actually works.

Comment: @chili555 No luck here with that one and 5.3.0-19

Comment: The aircrack-ng must have some issues with that kernel as no AP's found in scan with 5.3.0-19

Comment: Strange after another reboot into 5.3.0-19 the aircrack-ng driver works fine

Answer (score 0):

To use the aircrack-ng module from github, in terminal do

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Then check `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled if Ubuntu is installed in UEFI

Comment: Thanks for all of the expert advice and in such a short time. I went to Linux, Xubuntu back in July got fed up with Windows and dumped it. I have tried other kernels and the wift works with 5.4 but that version has a problem with Virtualbox. I'am able to run 19.10 without incident by using kernel 5.0.0.32. I do not use secure boot. I will now wait for the April 2020 LTS release since I have a system that is functional. Thanks again for the Help.